# Mapping users to all of their files(URLs) in a mysql database.

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

What I want is that when I have looked up a user in a table, I want to list all the file urls that the user have access to. My first thought was to have a field in the table with a list of file URLs. However, I have now understood that there are no such field type.

I was then thinking that maybe ForeignKeys might work, but I am having trouble getting my head around it.

Another solution maybe is to have one table for each user, with each row representing each file.

What would you say is best practice in this case? 
I am also going to expand into having shared files, but thought that I'd address this issue first.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). SO is not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service We try to fix your code, we do not write your code –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you explore the [JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html#json-values)

Answer (score 0):

2 tables: user and user_uri_permission? 2 columns in the second: userID and URI. When the User-URI pair is in the table the use has access.